# chrome.pageAction.setIcon does not work reliably

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, browser, webrequest

What is wrong about this code? When I try it in debug mode, it can change the icon and title every time, however when I try it without debug mode, it may not work sometimes(especially if I use mouse click for go to a website instead of using omnibox). I believe the filter may cause the problem, but I can not find the solution yet.

```
chrome.webRequest.onCompleted.addListener(
        function (details) 
        {
            var url = (new RegExp('^https://([^/@]+@)?([^/@]+)/(.*)').exec(details.url));
            var domain = url[2];

            if(domainCheck(domain)){
                    chrome.pageAction.setIcon({tabId: details.tabId, path: 'https_enforced.png'});
                    chrome.pageAction.setTitle({tabId: details.tabId, title: 'Secure connections enforced'});
            }
        }, { urls: ["https://*/*"]} 
    );
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem with,

```
chrome.webRequest.onCompleted.addListener(
function (details) 
{
    var url = (new RegExp('^https://([^/@]+@)?([^/@]+)/(.*)').exec(details.url));
    var domain = url[2];

    if(domainCheck(domain)){
            console.log("yesil")
            setTimeout(function(){chrome.pageAction.setIcon({tabId: details.tabId, path: 'https_enforced.png'})},100);
            setTimeout(function(){chrome.pageAction.setTitle({tabId: details.tabId, title: 'Secure connections enforced'})},100);
    }
}, { urls: ["https://*/*"]}
```

);